# is there a way to transform gz's gz.msgs.Model message to sensor_msgs/JointState?

Tags: ros2, gz-sim

i am publishing a robot state in gz using the JointStatePublisher plugin, which outputs a gz.msgs.Model message.
Is there a simple way to transform this into a sensor_msgs/JointState message or should I make a node that implements this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the bridge already takes care of this. The two message types are interchangeable:

- ros_topic_name: "model/joint_states"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/JointState"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Model"
  subscriber_queue: 1
  publisher_queue: 1
  lazy: false
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS